# Значення слова "вид"

Tags: значення-слів, вибір-слова

В Олександра Пономаріва зустіла таку інформацію:

> Вид і краєвид
>   Основне значення слова вид в українській мові — «обличчя»: «І стала жить Ганнусенька в сім’ї своїй, в роду, така русява, русенька, з рум’янцем на виду» (П. Тичина). З паронімічним російським вид наше слово збігається в таких значеннях: «ґатунок предметів, явищ» (основні види промислової продукції; елегія — вид лірики); «одиниця в системі класифікації тваринного та рослинного світу» (степові види рослин); «граматична категорія» (доконаний вид дієслова). Для решти значень російського слова вид є інші українські відповідники. Цього, на жаль, не беруть до уваги працівники деяких газет і пишуть: «Хлопець завжди був на виду» (треба на видноті); «Постійний вид на проживання, що потребує підтвердження раз на кілька років» (правильно посвідка на проживання); «За річкою відкривається чудовий вид на стару частину міста» (тут слід було вжити чудовий краєвид).
>
> Дехто заперечує проти того, що частина місцевості, яку видно з певної точки, зветься краєвид, мовляв, можна казати й вид. Залишаючись при своїй думці, хочу навести такі аргументи. В цьому значенні краєвид і вид є не синонімами, а дублетами, тобто словами, що нічим не відрізняються. Отже, один з них має відійти на другий чи й третій план. Чому варто віддати перевагу слову краєвид? Хоч би тому, що воно оригінальне українське, широко використовується в творах українських письменників різних поколінь: «Очі його розбігалися по неширокім, але розкішнім гірськім краєвиді» (І. Франко); «З скелі відкривається чудовий широкий краєвид на море» (М. Коцюбинський); «За вікном вагона щохвилини виростали все нові й нові краєвиди» (М. Руденко). Слово вид у такому значенні в словнику за редакцією Б. Грінченка не засвідчене, а в Словнику української мови підтверджене єдиною ілюстрацією, та й то з листування (а не з художнього чи публіцистичного твору) Лесі Українки. У листуванні ж, як відомо, припускається більша вільність при доборі лексичних та інших мовних засобів. Отже, краєвиди Києва, краєвиди Карпат, степові краєвиди.

Професор Пономарів уточнив, що як частина місцевості, яку видно з певної точки зору можливо вживати і вид і краєвид, хоча перевагу надавати краєвиду. А як щодо інших значень, адже у [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=8524&page=307) під словом вид подані всі ті значення, які Пономарів назвав помилковими:

> 2. Частина місцевості, яку видно, можна бачити; краєвид. Я вилізла тільки на одну [могилу], але зате на саму найвищу, – вид з неї дуже широкий і хороший (Леся Українка);
>
> (1) Вид на прожива́ння, юр. – те саме, що По́свідка на прожива́ння (див. по́свідка). Мені паспорт не потрібен, у мене студентський вид на проживання (Ф. Бурлака); Щоб отримати вид на проживання в Києві у 1843–1844 роках, Т. Шевченкові аудієнція у генерал-губернатора не була потрібна: цей документ поет отримав в Академії мистецтв (з газ.).
>
> (4) На виду́: а) відкритий, доступний для огляду, спостереження або контролю. – Важка служба! Клопотна [клопітна] служба! Перед усіма на виду (Панас Мирний); Хоча б от я – комбайн веду.., І тут у мене на виду, Як у орла – весь світ (М. Нагнибіда);

То ж чи варто дослухатись до порад Пономаріва, чи справді вживання даних виразів неправильне?

Comment: Виглядає як питання на точку зору... Пономарев однозначно вартий довіри. Не підводив)

Answer (score 1):

Проф.Пономарев обстоює значення слова **вид**, зафіксоване у словнику Грінченка

> **Вид**, -ду, м. 1) Лицо. Поганому виду нема стиду. Ном. № 3167. Глянь на
> вид та й кажи, що Свирид. Ном. № 6314. Увесь вид кропивою пожалив. МВ.
> І. 63. 2) Зрѣніе. Видом видати, слихом слихати. Шевч. 497. Ум. видок,
> видочок.

[Словник Грінченка](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/5035-vyd.html#show_point)

Спільнокореневі слова в Грінченка наближаються до значення **краєвиду**, але саме **краєвиду** якраз і нема.

> **Видовище**, -ща, с. Зрѣлище. Желех.
>
> **Видний**, -а, -е. 1) Ясный, видный.
> Ніч була славна, тепла, видна. Пирят. у. По видному. Когда свѣтло. 2)
> Видимый. Щоб лани широкополі і Дніпро, і кручі були видні. Шевч. 666.
> Ум. видненький, виднесенький.
>
> **Видіти**, -джу, -диш, гл. Видѣть. Желех.